# Does anything bad happen if an array(list) contains itself?

Tags: java

I noticed that if I do something like:

```
ArrayList anArray = new ArrayList();
anArray.add(anArray);
```

Netbeans auto-compiler doesn't seem to have any problem with it and I still seem to be able to reference everything. Are there any bad side effects of doing this?

Comment: For what do you need this?

Comment: No it will make a copy of it self. ArrayList should have code to handle self-copy

Comment: If you use a typed List then you can't do this as you would be a List<List<List<List...>

Comment: What would you expect to happen in this case? Something other than the list now containing a reference to itself? How would that be damaging (other than in recursive evaluation scenarios.)

Comment: @Nick You could have a `List<List<?>>`.

Comment: @user814628, would it really make a copy of itself, or would it contain a pointer to itself? I assume the latter, since all Java objects are passed by reference, but I'm curious about how it really works.  

I feel it would be analogous to writing down your home address, and keeping that address in a room in your home. Not a copy of the home in your home, just the address.

Answer (score 7):

I doubt anything bad would happen in most cases.

The problem would come if you were processing the list recursively in which case you'd end up with a stack overflow.

Comment: Or end up *in* Stack Overflow, asking whether it's okay for a list to contain itself.

Answer (score 5):

It gives a pretty interesting effect when you print things out:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList anArray = new ArrayList();
        anArray.add(anArray);

        for (Object o : anArray) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }

}
```

This printed out:

> [(this Collection)]

Other than that, I haven't figured out a way to break a program like this.  I don't think there's anything wrong with it.

---

As @wobblycogs mentioned, you have to be careful when you use recursion on the list, but that's not really a special case when you think about it.  It's just a circular dependency, similar to how this code gives a stackoverflow:

```
package com.sandbox;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        a.b = b;
        b.a = a;


        traverse(a);
    }

    private static void traverse(A a) {
        traverse(a.b);
    }

    private static void traverse(B b) {
        traverse(b.a);
    }


    private static class A {
        private B b;
    }

    private static class B {
        private A a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Right: that's Java avoiding the stack overflow issue mentioned by wobblycogs (since by default, converting an `ArrayList` to a string will show the contents of the list.

Comment: [Though if 2 cross-reference each other and you try to print one, you get a `StackOverflowError`](http://ideone.com/8yQh8S).

Comment: @Dukeling Which also makes sense: checking for "list[i] == this" is simple, and avoids the common case. Having to keep a list of "seen" lists just to avoid people shooting themselves in the foot like that raises the costs significantly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Here is a concrete example of a bad side effect.

In ArrayList, `hashCode` is implemented as follows.

```
public int hashCode() {
  int hashCode = 1;
  for (E e : this)
    hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
  return hashCode;
}
```

So if a list contains itself, and you call `hashCode()` on that list, you will get a StackOverflow exception.

In a real world use case, if you put this List in a Map then your program will fail.

So yes, there are bad side effects of adding a list to itself.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there's nothing inherently wrong with this.

(However, as pointed out, if you do a recursive operation on that object, you might end up in an infinite loop.)